# Where/how do I disable remote management on a Linksys WRT1200AC router?

Tags: networking, router

Where do I turn off remote management on a Linksys WRT1200AC router? I do not see that option on any of the menus on the router.

I am running the newest firmware and also see nothing in the manual about this. If someone enters my IP address in their browser they see my login page on my router. I do not want that to happen. Most routers have an option to disable this and I can't find that option on the WRT1200AC.

If this is not a WRT1200AC option how can I work around this behavior.

Comment: I am not familiar with this router but it seems like it can handle a DD-WRT firmware update and with DD-WRT installed, that setting can be disabled according to [this forum post](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=290539&view=previous&sid=6fedb8fbcb72e515ecd3b8dfae3b9a92). Have you tried contacting Linksys support?

Comment: I don't want to use DD-WRT - and yes I contacted Linksys support but no reply yet. I was thinking this was a common issue and someone might know here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So if you take a note of your internet connections IP address, and the port that remote administration uses, you can connect to your routers admin page from outside ?

Comment: Do you see in the router's menu, perhaps under Security, a section named "Remote Management IP Address" or similar? If it exists, setting it to `0.0.0.0` disallows all, while `255.255.255.255` allows all.

Comment: @theMezz It's highly recommended to use opensource firmwares [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt1200ac) or [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/), as the WRT1200AC was EOL'd [End of Life] by Linksys in 2018 _(it's missing 6yrs of security patches and all Linksys WRT versions, excl. WRT32X, are well supported by OpenWrt or DD-WRT)_, with remote access disabled by default. I'm more partial to OpenWrt since DD-WRT has extremely poor doc pages compared to [OpenWrt's](https://openwrt.org/docs/start) _(I run OpenWrt on all my WRT routers, excl the 32X, incl. the 1200AC)_

Comment: Thanks.. I wasn't aware of these things. Appreciate your time

Comment: @JW0914 - I decided to take your advice. Now I am trying to decide DD-WRT or OpenWRT .. seems like a no-brainer after realizing WRT1200AC firmware updates will  never be a reality.